# How to call a function when google pay billing is renewed

Tags: android, kotlin, google-pay, renewal

i am working on an streaming app project. i wish to use google pay subscription in order to get the package to access the video. i already implemented the google pay billing and acknowledge my subscription so when i tested it, the subscription is already working well. the problem is i can't detect when the subscription renewal happen so i can fire my function in order to add the package that the user should get. i already checked for google documentation but can't seem to find how to do this. i will really appreciate if someone can show me how to detect when the subscription renewal happening ?

Comment: Add documentation link you fallowed.

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/play-billing-codelab#3

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#kotlin and also this one